# If the limit of a real-valued function on $[a,b]$ exists on every point of the interval, is it necessary to be bounded on $[a,b]$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Let $f$ be a real-valued function on $[a,b]$, and the limit of $f$ exists on every point of $[a,b]$, then is $f$ bounded on this interval?

I guess $f$ is not necessary to be bounded but I couldn't find out an counterexample.

Comment: The typical proof which shows that a continuous function must be bounded on a closed interval works without any change in this case also. Just pick your favorite proof for the boundedness of continuous functions.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Exactly! I just tried the nested interval way and it works.

Comment: Great to hear that you understood the hint. You can try to do the same via least upper bound property. And if you wish you can try to apply Heine Borel too. These are the things I enjoyed when I learnt about these wonderful forms of completeness of real numbers.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh May I put it this way: the existence of limit at every point on the interval is what these proofs ask for continuity.

Comment: Yes that's the main idea. Here one more property in similar form. If $f$ is upper semi continuous on $[a, b] $, it is bounded above and it attains its maximum value in $[a, b] $.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it must be bounded.

Suppose that $f\colon[a,b]\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ is unbounded. For each $n\in\mathbb N$, let $x_n\in[a,b]$ be such that $f(x_n) \geqslant n$. By the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ has a convergent subsequence and we can assume without loss of generality that the whole sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to some $x_0\in[a,b]$. But then $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)$  does not exist (in $\mathbb R$) and therefore the limit $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: @Mark Note that this is a generalization of the theorem that says that every continuous function from $[a,b]$ into $\mathbb R$ must be bounded. If it is continuous, then it must have a limit at each point of its domain, but the reverse implication is false.

Comment: Fixed a minor typo. And +1

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks. And it was not mnor at all.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if wrong.

Let me rephrase this a bit:

$A: = \sup${$f(x); x \in [a,b]$ } $\in R \cup {\infty}.$

$(A = \infty$ , if $f$ is not bounded above).

1) If $A \in \mathbb{R}$ we are done.

2) Assume $f$ is not bounded on $[a,b]$.

There is a sequence $y_n \in f([a,b])$ such that for every $M$, positive, real, there is a $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for  $n \ge n_0$, $ n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have  $y_n \gt M.$

Let $x_n$ be such that $y_n = f(x_n).$

Since the sequence $x_n$ is bounded, $x_n \in [a,b]$, by Bolzano Weierstrass there is a convergent subsequence
$x_{n_k}$ with

$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} x_{n_k} = p \in [a,b],$ since [a,b] compact.

By assumption :

$ \lim_{ k \in \mathbb{N}} f(x_{n_k}) = L$ $\in \mathbb{R}$ exists.

Contradiction.

Hence $f$ is bounded.

Comment: This is almost same as the other answer here.

Comment: Yes. Just a little more explicit.Carlos fixed his minor typo.